# Pylint with pre-commit and EsLlint with husky

Tags: git, eslint, pylint, pre-commit.com, git-husky

I have a project with a frontend in JS and backend in Python.
Frontend had been configured with husky pre-commit hook.
Today I've configured Pylint with pre-commit library but husky hooks had been overwritten by that move.
Is it possible to combine pre-commit and husky libraries?
If not... what's the best way to solve the problem?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

pre-commit has a "migration mode" for running other existing hook frameworks.  It seems that husky is slightly too clever in their hook implementation for detecting what hook you're running -- they base it on the filename that's being executed

the way pre-commit's migration mode works is it takes any existing hook script (in this case, the hook script written by husky to `.git/hooks/pre-commit`) and adds the extension `.legacy`.  then during execution it runs that script.

but to husky, it looks like the `pre-commit.legacy` hook is running (!)

a little hack is to define `pre-commit.legacy` in `package.json` which seems to work:

#### package.json

```json
{
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit.legacy": "echo hello world"
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "husky": "^4.3.0"
  }
}
```

#### .pre-commit-config.yaml

```yaml
# See https://pre-commit.com for more information
# See https://pre-commit.com/hooks.html for more hooks
repos:
-   repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit-hooks
    rev: v3.2.0
    hooks:
    -   id: trailing-whitespace
    -   id: end-of-file-fixer
    -   id: check-yaml
    -   id: check-added-large-files
$ git commit -m "both"
husky > pre-commit.legacy (node v12.18.3)
hello world
Trim Trailing Whitespace.................................................Passed
Fix End of Files.........................................................Passed
Check Yaml...........................................(no files to check)Skipped
Check for added large files..............................................Passed
[master 7bd8807] both
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
```

that said, this seems fragile.  pre-commit is designed to support many different programming languages (even though it is written in python, it has native support for [10+ programming languages](https://pre-commit.com/#supported-languages) (**including javascript**))

---

A first place replacement might be to just call husky from a `local` pre-commit hook:

#### package.json

```json
{
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "echo hello world"
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "husky": "^4.3.0"
  }
}
```

#### `.pre-commit-config.yaml`

```yaml
# See https://pre-commit.com for more information
# See https://pre-commit.com/hooks.html for more hooks
repos:
-   repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit-hooks
    rev: v3.2.0
    hooks:
    -   id: trailing-whitespace
    -   id: end-of-file-fixer
    -   id: check-yaml
    -   id: check-added-large-files
-   repo: local
    hooks:
    -   id: husky-run-pre-commit
        name: husky
        language: system
        entry: node_modules/.bin/husky-run pre-commit
        pass_filenames: false
        always_run: true
```

#### execution

```
$ pre-commit run --all-files --verbose
Trim Trailing Whitespace.................................................Passed
- hook id: trailing-whitespace
- duration: 0.03s
Fix End of Files.........................................................Passed
- hook id: end-of-file-fixer
- duration: 0.03s
Check Yaml...............................................................Passed
- hook id: check-yaml
- duration: 0.05s
Check for added large files..............................................Passed
- hook id: check-added-large-files
- duration: 0.05s
husky....................................................................Passed
- hook id: husky-run-pre-commit
- duration: 0.07s

husky > pre-commit (node v12.18.3)
hello world
```

this solution however doesn't take advantage of pre-commit's js support, it just invokes the already-existing husky hooks

---

a more native solution would be to install js hooks directly with pre-commit, for example if you're using eslint:

```yaml
repos:
-   repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/mirrors-eslint
    rev: 'v7.9.0'  # Use the sha / tag you want to point at
    hooks:
    -   id: eslint
```

```
$ pre-commit  run --all-files
[INFO] Initializing environment for https://github.com/pre-commit/mirrors-eslint.
[INFO] Initializing environment for https://github.com/pre-commit/mirrors-eslint:eslint@7.9.0.
[INFO] Installing environment for https://github.com/pre-commit/mirrors-eslint.
[INFO] Once installed this environment will be reused.
[INFO] This may take a few minutes...
eslint...................................................................Passed
```

---

disclaimer: I am the author of pre-commit

Comment: hehe :))
Thank you for very useful and comprehensive answer.
I've tried to install eslint directly via pre-commit but it was complaining weirdly...
smth like `Configuration for rule "react/jsx-boolean-value" is invalid`...
That's why I've decided to take an old-good duck tape from the shelf :D

Comment: ah you probably want to [include your plugins](https://github.com/pre-commit/mirrors-eslint#using-eslint-with-pre-commit)

Comment: How can I get the native solution (3rd option) to run a command from the package.json? In husky I run lint and lint:fix to autocorrect linting issues when you check in. Also does the native solution use the project's `.eslintrc.json` for linting?

Answer (score 6):

A solution that works better for me, with the latest version of pre-commit (2.14.0) and husky (7.0.2) is to integrate pre-commit into husky, rather than the other way around.

In the `./husky/_/pre-commit` file, I added `pre-commit run`.

See below:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
. "$(dirname "$0")/_/husky.sh"

npx lint-staged
npx pretty-quick --staged
pre-commit run
```